# Theming node by content type in Drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, nodes, theming

I am building a drupal theme from scratch and I encountered a problem - when trying to theme a node by content type `<?php print render($content)`; ?> gives me nothing.
My template.php file:

```
<?php
function etalonestate_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
    if (isset($vars['node']->type)) {
        $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__' . $vars['node']->type;
    }
}
?>
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

In your tpl file, where you want to render($content) you have to put near first lines:

```
hook_preprocess_page();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Added the code you suggested in page--property.tpl.php. Got Fatal error: Call to undefined function hook_preprocess_page()

Comment: I think then you have to put it to your node.tpl.php. But i am sure that line will be requied. If this does not work, you have to replace "hook" to your own template name like mytemplatename_preprocess_page()